# Find Non-Friend Users LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables

**Users**
UserId
Username
FirstName
LastName

**FriendShips**
RelationId
UserId
FriendId

I need to return all users for which record doesnt exist in Friendship table . User can be friend of a user when his UserId is in Friendship tables UserId or FriendId column.

Comment: So far, you have listed a requirement. What's the question? Where are you stuck? As a starter, have you explored left joins in Linq?

Comment: You don't show the effort. This is the reason for getting downvotes. You seem to be not a newbie in stackoverflow. How that happened?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

*(note: this is free hand)*

```
int userId = 1;
var userFriends = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.ID = userId)
    .SelectMany(u => u.FriendShips)
    .Select(fs => fs.Friend);
var nonFriends = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.ID != userId)
    .Except(userFriends);
```

Note that `nonFriends` is a *query*. Call `.ToList()` to *evalutate* the query and return real data.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear but I need to get non-friends of a particular user. In query above there is no such condition.

Comment: Sorry but that didnt work . It shows user with userid 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather think of

```
var users = context.Users.Where(u => !u.Friendships.Any() && !u.Friendships1.Any());
```

As I understand the user can be at any side, `UserId` as well as `FriendId`